# Compile error for custom0 custom instruction

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to design simple accelerator to be familiar with RoCC and its interface in **spike**, and access it through RoCC command(such as custom0, custom1, ...)

In fact, I follow some guides described in cs250 lab4 from Berkeley by using master branch of riscv tools.(Actually, guides are different from this, but I could understand basic ideas, so I go through it.)

However, it seems that it does not work well.

First of all, I just build riscv tools in repository, and then I tried to compile dummy_rocc_test.c which resides in riscv-isa-sim/dumy_rocc

but it produces following outputs when using command:

`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o d ./dummy_rocc_test.c`

```
./dummy_rocc_test.c: Assembler messages:
./dummy_rocc_test.c:13: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 x0,a5,2,0'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:15: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 a5,x0,2,1'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:18: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 x0,a5,2,3'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:20: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 a5,x0,2,1'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:23: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 x0,a5,2,2'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:24: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 x0,a5,2,3'
./dummy_rocc_test.c:25: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 a5,x0,2,1'
```

Did I miss something before compiling this? or Should I have to modify some build option even though I want to use dummy extension?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/forum/#!topic/sw-dev/dbwc63vZTpQ

Answer (score 0):

By default recognition of `custom0`/`custom1` is off.

Try to use `-march` option with `custom` suffix:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv64imafdxcustom -o d ./dummy_rocc_test.c
```

Note: old toolchain use upper case ISA extensions symbols, i.e:

```
-march=RV64IMAFDXcustom
```